# Trying to Remember a Book that explored evolution of Dinosaurs to intelligence and then encountering humans

Tags: story-identification, books, alternate-history

Many, many years ago, I read a book where dinosaurs were assumed to have suvived the K-T event (or it never happened), and they evolved to intelligent species that used not only language (which combined sound, posture, and colour changes on their skin) but also used technology.  In the series, a human is captured or somehow gets integrated with one of the evolved dinosaur groups.

Again, from a very faint memory, the dinosaurs had a level of technology that would be about middle ages, and the humans were much more analogous to American Indian.

That's really all I can recall about the book, and I am trying to find it for my daughter to read.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you talking about "Mario Brothers". ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [West of Eden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_of_Eden) by Harry Harrison.

The lizard people use a biological based technology and genetic engineering. A scientist captures a human to study and teaches it to communicate in their language.

West of Eden is the first of three books that continue in Winter in Eden and Return to Eden.

Comment: THANK YOU!  It was driving me nuts trying to recall this book.  Now to tell my daughter.

Comment: @Larian - what age is she? This book might be a bit tough to properly appreciate in its fullness for a very young child (this is from experience of reading WoE translation at a fairly young age - 10 or 11 - and then re-reading recently in English). Just something to consider. +1, and welcome to scifi SE :)

Comment: @DVK, hey, a familiar name.  :)  She's 15, and was really intrigued by alternate history type books after reading Clan of the Cave Bear (a book I never read).

Comment: _Very_ different, but you might also want to look into Karel Capek's _The War With The Newts_, an incredibly good book for its age.

Comment: @Larian - "Clan" is an interesting book/series, though I'd hesitate to classify it as "alt-hist". If she's 15, she is definitely old enough for WoE. If she's into a more recent alternative history and not just paleolithic, give her Eric Flint's 1632 (aka Ring of Fire) multiverse series, as well as Turtledove and David Drake's Belisarius series.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you've already found the book described, but another based on a similar premise is [Dinotopia](http://www.dinotopia.com/). Lavishly illustrated, and more an exploration than a story, really.

Comment: I used to watch that when I was little, but the story wasn't as compelling as the one my dad told me about.