# A book series about a Prehistoric Man versus Intelligent Reptilians

Tags: novel, prehistoric, story-identification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to Remember a Book that explored evolution of Dinosaurs to intelligence and then encountering humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/trying-to-remember-a-book-that-explored-evolution-of-dinosaurs-to-intelligence-a)

In this series prehistoric man is constantly fighting a reptilian species that uses genetically altered species to do their bidding. For example, a whale that has a water-tight "hold" they can sit in while the outside is armor plated.

Another thing the book presents is that the female reptiles are the dominant gender. The males mate with two females, the eggs are fertilized in the females, transferred back to males and are finally carried by males until maturation.

Comment: I am seeing a black cat here (in other words, I have a strong feeling this is a dupe)

Comment: Ahhhh I did not see that when I did my search, I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the [West of Eden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_of_Eden) trilogy by Harry Harrison.

Comment: Didn't relise it was a trilogy, are the 2nd two books any good? will have to look them up.

Comment: Been a long time since I read those. I recall liking them.

Comment: Yes very good series, I read them years ago.