# Fiction novel or movie about sentient dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, dinosaurs

I remember parts of a story about some researchers finding a society of sentient dinosaurs. I believe they lived underground. From what I recall there were some steam punk elements and I think crystals were important.

From what I recall (this might be wrong) there was a book and also a movie about that story.

In the process, humans lived with these dinosaurs. I am not sure if that was like that from the beginning or if that happened later.

Any idea what that story might be?

Comment: Possibly *Dinotopia*, but I've only seen pieces of that setting over someone else's shoulder.

Comment: Could also be: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/trying-to-remember-a-book-that-explored-evolution-of-dinosaurs-to-intelligence-a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Dinotopia**

[image]

The description sounds like elements of both the book series and the filmed version

***Society of sentient dinosaurs***

> Dinotopia is a fictional utopia created by the artist and writer James
>   Gurney. It is the setting for his illustrated book series about an
>   island inhabited by humans and sentient dinosaurs who have formed a
>   complex, interdependent society.

***Steam punk elements***
Example: Dragoncopter:

> The Dragoncopter was an experimental aircraft designed and built by
>   Arthur Denison. It was a steam-powered ornithopter built to resemble a
>   dragonfly. The engine also used kerosene in some capacity. The machine
>   was primarily a glider; the engine was only capable of providing five
>   minutes of powered flight.

[image]

***Crystals*** (*note: appears to only be prominent in the filmed version*)

> Sunstones are the power-source of Dinotopia. They provide protection
>   to the island by amending a high-pitched sound when placed in a
>   sunstone holder that keep the Carnivores inside the Rainy Basin and
>   the Pteranodons in the lower half of Canyon City. All towns and cities
>   own a sunstone for protection in the miniseries and tv series.

***Filmed***

*sources*:

http://www.dinotopia.com/

http://dinotopia.wikia.com/wiki/Dragoncopter

http://dinotopia.wikia.com/wiki/Sunstones

Comment: This is amazing! I habe been looking for this story for years now! Thank you!